# Using PHP replace regex with regex

Tags: php, regex, string, hashtag

I want to replace hash tags in a string with the same hash tag, but after adding a link to it

Example:

```
$text = "any word here related to #English must #be replaced."
```

I want to replace each hashtag with

```
#English ---> <a href="bla bla">#English</a>
#be ---> <a href="bla bla">#be</a>
```

So the output should be like that:

```
$text = "any word here related to <a href="bla bla">#English</a> must <a href="bla bla">#be</a> replaced."
```

Comment: Have a look at php documentation of preg_replace and how to work with backreferences: http://be2.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: @jan You need more than that if you wish to prevent xss :)

Comment: @Jack, the question was about a string replace with a regular expression. I don't follow your reference to xss

Comment: @jan The output is HTML, so you should be on your guard ... though, probably in this case there are no severe issues.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
$input_lines="any word here related to #English must #be replaced.";
$result = preg_replace("/(#\w+)/", "<a href='bla bla'>$1</a>", $input_lines);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/edcoU)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**:

```
any word here related to <a href='bla bla'>#English</a> must <a href='bla bla'>#be</a> replaced.
```

Comment: your demo link is outdated.

Comment: The demo link is broken: `Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 8):

This should nudge you in the right direction:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/#(\w+)/', function($match) {
    return sprintf('<a href="https://www.google.com?q=%s">%s</a>', 
        urlencode($match[1]), 
        htmlspecialchars($match[0])
    );
}, htmlspecialchars($text));
```

See also: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Comment: the var $map you mentioned here ... is dynamic it may be any hashtage like #ask, #Answer, ....

Comment: @user1272589 So the `bla bla` link is always the same?

Comment: no actually it will be like #English the link will be www.google.com?q=English ....... something like that

Comment: @user1272589 That makes it a lot easier; updated my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to refer to the whole match from the string replacement pattern all you need is a `$0` placeholder, also called replacemenf backreference.

So, you want to wrap a match with some text and your regex is `#\w+`, then use

```
$text = "any word here related to #English must #be replaced.";
$text = preg_replace("/#\w+/", "<a href='bla bla'>$0</a>", $text);
```

Note you may combine `$0` with `$1`, etc. In case you need to enclose a part of the match with some fixed strings you will have to use capturing groups. Say, you want to get access to both `#English` and `English` within one `preg_replace` call. Then use

```
preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href='path/$0'>$1</a>", $text)
```

Output will be `any word here related to <a href='path/#English'>English</a> must <a href='path/#be'>be</a> replace`.