# regex for specific url id

Tags: php, regex

I want to change the id `partner=852501` to `partner=985412` in my code, but stuck in this step. Example:

```
http://a-ads.com/?partner=852501
```

My attempt:

```
([1-z0-9\/]+)\/\/(a-ads\.com\/?)
```

How to do the right thing?

Comment: Have you chacked [Using php replace regex with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040272/using-php-replace-regex-with-regex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: [`partner=\K[^&]+`](https://regex101.com/r/qZrM5h/1)

Details:

- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match
- `[^&]+` Match a single character not present in the list `&` one and unlimited times

**PHP code**:

```
preg_replace('/partner=\K[^&]+/', '985412', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

**preg_replace** you can replace the value

```
 $string = 'http://a-ads.com/?partner=852501';
 $your = 985412;

 echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', $your, $string);
```

**UPD:** The value can be obtained with the help of preg_match

```
preg_match('/partner=(\d+)/', $string, $match);

echo $match[1];
```